# What´s up with multithreading in php 7

Tags: multithreading, php-7

I have read that one of expected features of PHP 7 is native Multithreading (http://www.phpzag.com/php-7-expected-features-for-php-7/) but now it is not listed in list of features http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php Do you know if it was fulfilled or not? I didn´t found any official statements.

Comment: Wow, that article is so wrong, it must be coming straight off phpclasses. It managed to get two out of five points about right!

Comment: WTH is wrong with people. This question is good and useful, why so many downvote. St***** php folks.

Answer (score 17):

There is no native Multithreading in PHP7.

You can find the official changelog for PHP7 at http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php. Anything not listed in there is not in PHP7 obviously.

To learn about the new features of PHP7 and differences to 5.6, consider reading the upgrade guide at http://php.net/migration70.

If you need threading in PHP, consider installing http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php

Answer (score 6):

I am to announce that threading will NEVER be in php ( at least on web server). Pthread 3 officially restricted to CLI only saying multi threading in webserver does not make sense.

too bad, multithread is so useful and convenient in real world usage...

Answer (score 0):

> I am to announce that threading will NEVER be in php ( at least on web server).

Seems like PHP 8 has threads with the fibers feature: https://php.watch/versions/8.1/fibers

Comment: That's not true multithreading like what you can do with pthreads or parallel.  That's more like cooperative multitasking.